# I have 2 loops and results is not good

Tags: vba, loops

I have 2 loops, but unfortunately it does not work as it should. I want to take the first specific cells every 50 rows and paste them into another tab every 31 rows. Unfortunately, as it is now, I copy only one data range and paste it into the second tab repeating 332 times. I know what it results from, but I have no idea how to write it differently.

```
Sub makro3()

    Dim X As Integer, X_max As Integer

    X_max = 332

    Y_max = 10292

    For X = 0 To X_max Step 50

        Sheets("Arkusz1").Select
        Cells(14 + X, 3).Select
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:T31").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("dane").Select

        For Y = 0 To Y_max Step 31
            Cells(2 + Y, 7).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        Next Y

    Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: 1st, there is no need to use `Select` and you should try and remove it from your code. 2nd, when you say that you are trying to copy the first specific cells, how do you define this? Within your code you select a single cell with `Cells(14 + X, 3).Select` but then proceed to select a static range `ActiveCell.Range("A1:T31").Select`. Not sure what you are getting at here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub makro3()

    Dim X As Long, Y As Long
    Dim X_max As Long: X_max = 332
    Dim Y_max As Long: Y_max = 10292

    For X = 0 To X_max Step 50

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1").Cells(14 + X, 3).Copy

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dane")

            For Y = 0 To Y_max Step 31
                .Cells(2 + Y, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Next Y

        End With

    Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: This will loop and past 1 cell of information. The OP specified a range of cells to paste.

Comment: Hi, I have found another solution. Z_max=X_max/50 

For Z = 0 To Z_max 
X=Z*50 
Y=Z*31

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub makro3() 
Dim X As Integer, X_max As Integer
Dim Y As Integer, Y_max As Integer
Dim Z_max As Double



X_max = 16564
Y_max = 10292
Z_max = X_max / 50

For Z = 0 To Z_max
    X = Z * 50
    Y = Z * 31
    Sheets("Arkusz1").Select
    Cells(14 + X, 3).Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:T31").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("dane").Select

    Cells(2 + Y, 7).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Next Z

End Sub
```